# Higman embedding theorem

Tags: group-theory

[The Higman Embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_embedding_theorem) says that any finitely generated recursively presented group can be embedded in a finitely presented group.

My question is if one can embed such a group **as a normal subgroup** into a finitely presented group?

Comment: Moved to MO 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73076/higman-embedding-theorem

Comment: Mustafa: would you mind posting a short answer indicating that Mark Sapir answered your question on MO, so that this question can be considered closed? There are now two votes to close as "too localized" which I don't think it is.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in Mo by Mark Sapir

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73076/higman-embedding-theorem